# Non-recursive binary search

Tags: java, binary

I'm trying to write this bSearch() method. My professor provided some pseudocode for it; however, I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement some of it. I have coded most of it; however, I have two lines that are still not quite right. I have bolded the sections in which I am have difficulty with. Thank you!

```
private int bSearch(Item SearchItem)
{
    int low = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int high = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int foundPosition = -1;
    int middle;
    Item midPos;

    while (low <= high && **we should continue looping**)
    {
        middle = (low + high) / 2;
        midPos = MyStore.get(middle);

        if (SearchItem.equals(midPos) == true)
        {
            foundPosition = middle;
            **quit while loop**
        }
        else if (SearchItem.compareTo(middle) < midPos)
        {
            high = middle - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            low = middle + 1;
        }
    }
    return foundPosition;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. You've made a decent start but here are some suggestions.

1. you really don't need to store `foundPosition` - just return the position inside the loop or -1 if the item isn't found
2. ideally you would be able to get the lower (generally 0) and upper range from the collection `myStore`. This makes more sense than using min and max integer values.
3. you don't need to compare booleans to true - just use the expression in your statement
4. `compareTo` returns a 0, negative or positive depending on result

That would leave you with something like the following:

```
private int bSearch(Item searchItem) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = myStore.size() - 1;

    while (low <= high) {
        int middle = (low + high) / 2;
        int comparison = searchItem.compareTo(myStore.get(middle));

        if (comparison < 0) {
            low = middle + 1;
        } else if (comparison > 0) {
            high = middle - 1;
        } else {
            return middle;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Note that I've changed capitalisation and formatting to something considered more standard on this site (and elsewhere).